# Spark - Execute Scala script from Java and get the result

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

My application requires a series of values to be calculated using spark and i'm trying to make it metadata driven.

```
[
  {
    key   :  "myKeyName",
    logic :  "scala script"
  }
  ...
]
```

I have a json that resembles above, which will be submitted with the "app.jar" to Spark. In the main() of spark job, I'm looking to load this json and execute the "logic" script in spark and get the value for the key. I think [SparkContext.submitJob()](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.1/api/java/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.html#submitJob(org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD,%20scala.Function1,%20scala.collection.Seq,%20scala.Function2,%20scala.Function0)) is what I wan't but I'm not sure. Still looking for solutions in the web. Any help is deeply appreciated, thanks in advance.

The bundled jar is submitted to spark via SparkLauncher:

```
final SparkLauncher launcher = new SparkLauncher()
                .setAppResource("path/to/app.jar")
                .setMainClass("the.main.class")
                .setMaster("spark.master")
                .setConf(SparkLauncher.DRIVER_MEMORY, "3g");
//add the other dependent jar files
launcher.startApplication();
```

PS: the Spark application is implemented as a service in Docker.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out by myself.

```
//...
import scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain;
import javax.script.ScriptContext;
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptException;
//...

private void scalaJob(SparkSession sparkSession, Dataset<Row> someData){

    ScriptEngine e = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("scala");

    //tell scala to use the classpath same as java
    ((IMain)e).settings().classpath().append(System.getProperty("java.class.path"));

    //passing on some foo and bar
    e.getContext().setAttribute("sparkSession",sparkSession, ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE);
    e.getContext().setAttribute("someData",someData, ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE);

    try {

        //hello world

        String script = "object HelloWorld {\n"; 
        script += "def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {\n";
        script += "println(\"Hello, world!\")\n";
        script += "}\n";
        script += "}\n";
        script += "HelloWorld.main(Array())";
        e.eval(script);

        //some serious work

        script = "import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession\n";
        script += "import org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset\n"
        script += "import org.apache.spark.sql.Row\n";

        script += "val processedData = someData.asInstanceOf[Dataset[Row]]\n";
        script += "processedData.show(false)\n"

        script += "processedData\n";

        //getting back the result of serious work

        Dataset<Row> ds = (Dataset<Row>) e.eval(script);
        ds.show();

    } catch (ScriptException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        System.exit(1);
    }
}
```

The `script` is loaded from the json metadata.

PS: This is just an example, not the production code.